# Fromatting ZMQ logger in python

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a multithreaded python program that I've implemented zmq logger into to log.
I'm trying to use JSON event logging to parse the logs in post process yet I can't seem to make the log worker to log in the required format, I just get the message as given to the function and the formatting doesn't actually works.

---

Here's a code very similar to what I'm using:

**zmq_logger**

```
import datetime
import logging
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import pathlib
import time

import zmq
from zmq.log.handlers import PUBHandler

LOG_QUEUE = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:9142'


class LoggerListener(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, logging_queue_string, logging_file_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.logging_queue_string = logging_queue_string
        self.logging_file_path = logging_file_path

    def run(self) -> None:
        listen(
            log_queue_string=self.logging_queue_string,
            logging_file_path=self.logging_file_path
        )


def listen(log_queue_string: str, logging_file_path: pathlib.Path):
    print('Starting logger listener')
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    sub = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sub.bind(log_queue_string)
    sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"tester")
    with logging_file_path.open('w') as f:
        while True:
            level, message = sub.recv_multipart()
            topic = level.decode('ascii').split('.')[0]
            message = message.decode('ascii')
            print(topic, message)
            if message.endswith('\n'):
                # trim trailing newline, which will get appended again
                message = message[:-1]
            f.write(message)
            f.flush()



def log_worker(log_queue_string: str, logger_topic: str):
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    pub = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
    pub.connect(log_queue_string)

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    # TODO: Pass to configs
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = PUBHandler(pub)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    jsformatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter('(level) (message)')
    handler.setFormatter(jsformatter)
    handler.root_topic = logger_topic.encode()
    logger.handlers.append(handler)

    return logger


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger_process = LoggerListener(logging_queue_string=LOG_QUEUE, logging_file_path=pathlib.Path('./test_log.json'))
    logger_process.start()
    logger_process.join()
```

**Dummy program**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing as mp
from zmq_logger import log_worker, LOG_QUEUE


def dummy_function(logger):
    logger.debug('inside dummy function')


class JSONTester(mp.Process):
    @staticmethod
    def run():
        logger = log_worker(log_queue_string=LOG_QUEUE, logger_topic='tester')
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
            logger.debug('before execution')
            dummy_function(logger)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jt = JSONTester()
    jt.start()
    jt.join()
```

The logging I'm getting from to test_log.json:

```
before execution
inside dummy function
```

**Please note:**

1. I've tried to receive json from the log_worker but I't failed to parse
2. I'm trying to use jsonlogger to format in the json events logging format but even with simple logging formatting I couldn't get it to pass logs in the correct format.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Hod

Answer (score 0):

A quick look in zmq PUBHandler and I figure it out.
It seems that the PUBHandler.setHandler() isn't implemented and doesn't overrides the class formatters. 
So in my code:

```
def log_worker(log_queue_string: str, logger_topic: str):
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    pub = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
    pub.connect(log_queue_string)

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    # TODO: Pass to configs
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = PUBHandler(pub)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    jsformatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter('(level) (message)')
    handler.formatters[logging.DEBUG] = jsformatter
    handler.root_topic = logger_topic.encode()
    logger.handlers.append(handler)

    return logger
```

Another solution can be implementing the setHandler method yourself.